# Console, windows and web applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have VS Express2013 for web installed. I want to build all applications like console, windows and web. I noticed I can not make console applications in it.  Do I need all different versions to download or is any way i can do all projects in one?

Comment: Is it VS Community 2013?

Comment: no it is VS express 2013. can i download VS community without removing VSexpress?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express has a separate version for each language/technology. Visual Studio Community 2015 however, will make available all the types of projects and it is also free.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try VS community 2015. Do i need to uninstall VS 2013 express for web which is already on my windows10?